# jQuery return modal when a page from exit or unload with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a dialog function with jQueryUI but I need this function is fired when the user make click on close page or when leave page.

The next code show an alert when I do click on close or leave the page, but I need a modal box, not an alert.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here';
});
```

How can I do to return a modal with jQuery? It´s posible??

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `unload()` event

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
    return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*edit: all of that doesn't matter because*

#### Manipulating the `beforeunload` and `unload` events is very limited and unreliable across browsers

> Starting with Firefox 4, Chrome 51, Opera 38 and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown instead of the returned string. For example, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

From [window.onbeforeunload on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

As a potential alternative if your goal is user retention or some sort of "last resort" offer for users just about to leave your site, you could look into [exit intent popups](https://www.google.com/search?q=exit+intent+popup+jquery). They produce the desired effect but instead of using `window.unload`, they are triggered by the mouse leaving the browser in a way that suggests the user intends to leave your site.